# Protecting iOS backend from being abused

Tags: ios, security, encryption

First, let me ensure you that this is not a duplicate of the following question [SO:ensure access from iPhone only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409719/iphone-app-with-a-server-backend-how-to-ensure-all-access-is-from-the-iphone-a)

In short, I have an app that make backend lookups. When developing it, I used AES-256 encryption for the data so that only the app could read the responds from the backend i.e. the JSON from the server were encrypted.

When it came to releasing the app, the iOS release process says "you cannot have any type of encryption in your app without a certificate (which I guess is really hard to come by) unless it's for user authentication, then it's ok".

That sort of disqualifies my tactic, and frankly also the tactic discussed in the SO-question I linked to above.

So, any thoughts on how to accomplish this without breaking Apple's stipulated terms of usage?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) It's easy to get the needed documentation to use encryption in your app. 2) There's no need for encryption. Just use `https` (SSL) to communicate between your iOS app and your server and setup your server to only accept https requests.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the fast reply, sincerely. On 1) It seemed to me to involve contact with at least one government like agency of the US. So... easy seems like a matter of opinion. On 2) I use admob in my app i.e. I need it to allow for http calls. However, if I make https calls to my server and still allows for admob http calls, that could work, right?

Comment: How you communicate with any other server (such as AdMob) is irrelevant to your needs to communicate with your own server. Use https when connecting to your server and the data is encrypted. That's the whole point of SSL.

Comment: ok, got it. but doesn't connecting with SSL (or isn't it TLS these days) _also_ require me to get the approval in point 1? I hope you see what I mean.

Comment: That's debatable (and a separate question). Do some searching on whether making an SSL connection to a server means you need to state "yes, my app uses encryption".

Comment: Just as an FYI to anyone else who reads this: Having researched this very quickly it seems like Yes, you need a so called ERN (a certificate from the US obtained through a not so easy process) if you are using any type of encryption, including if your app uses https. So, in essence, consult your conscience on what to do but the right thing is to obtain the certificate. See https://carouselapps.com/2015/12/09/mac-ios-applications-breaking-rules-removed/

Comment: Also, there are comments on that article discussing it and some are leaning towards it not being so etc etc. But my interpretation, fwiw, is that if you want to be on the safe side, get a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

i am using AES in multiple projects with the similar concept you have described. went through app approval with no problem. just tick that option. you are technically authenticating user communnication with backend in each packet ;)

Comment: Well, yes, I could do that. But I'm too "clean" or... well, call it what you like. I don't like breaking the rules and that's in effect what you are doing. The fact that you are getting away with it is not a guarantee that person X also will get away with it. Please be aware, I'm not judging you, I'm just saying it's not an option for me. Thanks still for taking the time to answer.

Comment: it is not breaking rules. it is just the way you comprehend the law. i wouldn't let nobody to snoop on user's data. i am sure apple would not authorize it if it would not be ok. especially now after all that noise with FBI. and judging by the number of posts regarding AES, CommonCrypto or CryptoSwift i am pretty sure i'm not the only one using it. so do whatever you think is "clean" but i'm saying that you can authenticate in each packet, protect your users and pass the approval.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but Apple doesn't care either way since they are not responsible for what YOU do. If/when someone starts asking questions about your apps, Apple will refer the asking party to you and state that you have sole responsibility for your app. What you are doing is FINE as long as you have a permit for it. That permit is not something Apple cares about as per the above statement. Disclaimer: This is how I have understood it. I can, of course, be wrong but I'm not taking any chances. I'm getting the permit.